# Iterating over columns and reassigning values - Pandas/Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Trying to use a for loop to iterate over columns and change Yes and No's to 1 and 0.

For some reason, I am getting an invalid type comparison error when attempting this:

Panda DataFrame has multiple columns, one of them being "Combined"

```
for col,row in d.iteritems():
    d.loc[d[col] == 'No', col] = 0
    d.loc[d[col] == 'Yes', col] = 1
```

TypeError: invalid type comparison

For comparison, I can successfully perform this on a single column without issues:

```
d.loc[d['Combined'] == 'No', 'Combined'] = 0
d.loc[d['Combined'] == 'Yes', 'Combined'] = 1
```

Any reason why plugging the value of col into the loc function in place of the actual column name throws an error? Does it need to be converted to a string or something before?

Comment: It is working fine for me. Can you share the complete traceback?

Comment: I think you can just do: `d = d.replace('No', 0).replace('Yes', 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be columns which are taking integer values and for those rows its an "invalid comparison". So just check if its an instance of str and you are good to go.

```
for col,row in d.iteritems():
    if isinstance(row[0], str):
        d.loc[d[col] == 'No', col] = 0
        d.loc[d[col] == 'Yes', col] = 1
```

And for the same reason

```
d.loc[d['Combined'] == 'No', 'Combined'] = 0
```

this is working perfectly, as its already a column with string values.

Comment: That explains it perfectly, thanks! Would this be the optimal way of going about changing those values in a dataframe or would there be a better way than what I'm attempting?

Comment: There are better ways... what you are doing is "preprocessing the data". And sklearn has a function for this thing only. Heres a link - http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html

Comment: `isinstance(row, str)` will never return True as the type of row is Series. You need to check the dtype of the Series.

Comment: @ayhan I actually typed row[0] when testing but didn't write it in the answer. Edited it! Thanks!